# How to split every string element in an array of Strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
    function anagrams(word, words) {
       var returnArray = [];
       var wordToTest= word.split("").sort();
       for(i=0; i<=words.length; i++){
          var wordssToTest = words[i].split("");
          wordssToTest.sort();
          if(wordssToTest==wordToTest){
             returnArray.push(wordssToTest);
          }
       }
     return returnArray;


    }
```

Hello!
I need to create a function, where the input is a string (word) and an array of strings (words).
My objective is to return a new array, which will contain a list of all the words in the 'words' string that are anagrams to the 'word' string.

I wrote the code, yet it doesn't recognize the `words[i].split("")` function on the 5th line, says it's an unknown **property** of undefined..
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You used `<=` instead of `<` in the for loop. Correct code:

```
function anagrams(word, words) {
       var returnArray = [];
       var wordToTest= word.split("").sort();
       for(i=0; i<words.length; i++){
          var wordssToTest = words[i].split("");
          wordssToTest.sort();
          if(wordssToTest==wordToTest){
             returnArray.push(wordssToTest);
          }
       }
     return returnArray;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much more simpler solution using [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
function anagrams(word, words) {
  return words.filter(el =>
    word.split('').sort().toString() === el.split('').sort().toString()
  );
}
```